# I programmed a submit button to redirect the user to another page but it says the local host is not found

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I'm making a website in HTML and C# with ASP.NET on Web Application and I programmed the submit button as soo, when the user click it, goes to a page called L_Page.cshtml, but when the I click the button, it seems to not be working:
[image: This localhost page can't be found No web page was found for the web address https://localhost /L_Page.cshtml?]

Here is the way i programmed the button and the beginning of the form and the button at the end:

```
<body>
    <div class="testbox">
        <form action="L_Page.cshtml">
```

```
<div class="btn-block">
                <button type="submit" id="btnSubmit" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click()">Send</button>
            </div>
```

I need help on how to, when someone clicks the button, it redirects to the so called L_Page.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: Unless you are doing something strange, you don't put  the name of the cshtml file in the URL. The URL should contain a string that is [mapped to a controller action](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mscratnesh/action-methods-in-mvc/#:~:text=If%20a%20user%20requests%20an,one%20mapping%20with%20user%20interactions.). The controller's action method chooses the view, which is a cshtml file. The end user doesn't see the file name or extension.

Comment: Also, underscores in URLs are not common and are [discouraged](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/guidelines/url-structure?hl=en&visit_id=637454815490047762-3494855827&rd=1). The URL can be seen by the end user so it should be something readible.

Comment: @JohnWu btw thx for the reply. I read the article you posted on your reply however I'm still unsure on how to do it. Can you help me plz?

Comment: @JohnWu i like that "Unless you are doing something strange" disclaimer much

Comment: @MichaelSchönbauer I'm probably just doing everything wrong, i'm pretty new to this stuff xD

Comment: @GuilhermeOliveira Sorry but I'm not going to write you an answer that is more detailed than the page I linked, not for free anyway.  I suggest an internet search for an appropriate ASP.NET tutorial, or try PluralSight.

Comment: I think all that you're trying to do with your button function is something similar to `return RedirectToAction("actionResultView", "controller");`

Comment: @JohnWu thank you for your help anyways, appreciate it! I'll try to understand the code xD. Have a great day.

Comment: Hello @Chris! I think in my other thread someone replyed with something similar however I don't know what are the "actionResultView" and the "controller". What do I need to replace it with?

Comment: This will most likely help you greatly  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/overview?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: Please read the following and modify your code sample accordingly so we can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example